# How to format the axis values in an asp.net mvc 3 chart using C# and razor?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, mschart

I'm trying to create a chart in `asp.net mvc 3` using the `system.web.helpers` namespace.  However, I cannot find a way to format the values of the Y Axis.  Currently they are display as `1000,2000,3000,4000` when I would like them to be `$1,000,$2,000,$3,000,$4,000`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There does not seem to be a way to do this.  Marking this as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Please read [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx).

I think you need something resembling this code:

```
LabelStyle style = new LabelStyle();
style.Format = "$#,##0";
myChart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.LabelStyle = style;
```

Comment: Actually that's using the using System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting namespace, I'm using the using System.Web.Helpers namespace.  It seems like a very odd omission on the part of Microsoft.